# navigation stack and static map

Tags: ros, navigation, stack, static-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is the importance of static map in navigation stack?? and what if it doesn't exist??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261204/navigation-stack-and-static-map/) by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The static map is e.g. the floor plan of your building and used for global navigation. (How to drive from room A to room B). You don't have to use it, but without it your robot would not know which path to take from A to B.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-31**:
does the local planner have access to the static map?